# Bootstrap table filtering not working

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add filtering for bootstrap table. I added two attributes, I round them in code below. Why it not working? What else should I do?

```
    <table id="clients-table" class="table table-striped table-condensed" 
           data-toggle="table" data-show-toggle="true" data-cache="false" data-show-refresh="true"
           data-url="../data.json"
           //-----------------------------------------------------
           data-filter-control="true"
           //-----------------------------------------------------
           data-side-pagination="server"
           data-search="true" data-sort-name="Id" data-sort-order="desc"
           data-pagination="true" data-page-size="25">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="Id" data-sortable="true">Id</th>
                <th data-field="Email" data-sortable="true">E-Mail</th>
                <th data-field="CompanyName" data-sortable="true">Firma</th>
                <th data-field="Name" data-sortable="true">Imię i nazwisko</th>
                <th data-field="Phone" data-sortable="true">Nr telefonu</th>
                <th data-field="UserType" data-sortable="true">Typ</th>
                <th data-field="PricingType" data-sortable="true" 
                //----------------------------------------------------------
                    data-filter-control="select" 
                //----------------------------------------------------------
                    >Cennik</th>
                <th data-field="LastSynchronizationOn" data-sortable="true">Synchronizacja</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

I have alse some JS scipt to service error from server

```
   $('#clients-table').bootstrapTable({
        onLoadError: function (status) {
            SetErrorMessage('Wystąpił błąd serwera podczas wczytywania danych. Skontaktuj się z administratorem.');
        }
    });
```

I also attached this scripts

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/locale/bootstrap-table-pl-PL.min.js"></script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/filter/bootstrap-table-filter.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: *Aside:* What's the story behind those `//` comments? HTML comments are `<!-- ... -->`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want filter with select, i think it works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/locale/bootstrap-table-pl-PL.min.js"></script>

 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/filter/bootstrap-table-filter.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<table id="clients-table" class="table table-striped table-condensed" 
           data-toggle="table" 
           data-show-toggle="true" 
           data-cache="false" 
           data-show-refresh="true"
           data-url="data.json"
           data-filter-control="true"
           data-side-pagination="server"
           data-search="true" 
           data-sort-name="Id" 
           data-sort-order="desc"
           data-pagination="true" 
           data-page-size="25">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="Id" data-sortable="true">Id</th>
                <th data-field="Email" data-sortable="true">E-Mail</th>
                <th data-field="PricingType" data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="select">Cennik</th>
                <th data-field="LastSynchronizationOn" data-sortable="true">Synchronizacja</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

  <script>
    var $table = $('#clients-table');
    
    $table.bootstrapTable();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And your data.json:

```js
{
  "total": 800,
  "rows": [
   {
  "Id": 1,
  "Email": "email@gmail.com",
  "PricingType": "Value 1",
  "LastSynchronizationOn": "date"
 },
 {
  "Id": 2,
  "Email": "other@gmail.com",
  "PricingType": "Value 2",
  "LastSynchronizationOn": "date"
 }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had attached CSS files, but without this "http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css".

When I link it I get error about CORS "Font from origin 'http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1294' is therefore not allowed access."

Do you have any idea what should I change?

Comment: You put: var $table = $('#clients-table'); $table.bootstrapTable();

Comment: I updated my post, I had before similar code. Please look at this

Comment: Your data.json, have the same structure? "rows": []

Comment: Yes, struct is the same. I see rows read from db, but I not see filter input. Html generated for filter is "<div class="fht-cell"></div>"

Comment: Your problem, is the input filter or select filter?

Comment: select / dropdownlist

Comment: There is link how it looks like at this moment http://postimg.org/image/pr0on4dc3/d9f7b929/

Comment: Strange, the select works here: http://postimg.org/image/5pfezlhdb/ Your console show some error?

Comment: Only this error with CORS. Please look at top of our conversation

Comment: I think it isn't your problem, but you can switch by this url: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: I code which you gave me as example I get the same error, but it show dropdownlist in your example.

Comment: Now it works, in main layout there was linked js file which override this feature. Thanks for your time and help :)